# How can I change the umask for a user when he logs on to an alternate group?

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, umask

I want the `umask` to be more permissive for users when they switch to a non-default group. Just to demonstrate what I mean:

```
$ id
uid=500(beamin) gid=500(beamin) groups=10(wheel)

$ umask
0022

$ sg wheel

$ umask # I want this to now be 0002 instead
0022
```

I was thinking of adding a script to `/etc/profile.d/` that would look like this:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -ge 500 ] && [ "`id -g`" -ne "`id -u`" ]; then
   umask 0002
fi
```

I got `500` because all our user `uid`s are larger or equal to that. Is this the best way to do it? Or does someone have something that makes more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is fine. In a shell script you can use:

```
(umask 022;exec sg wheel )
```

Test with:

```
umask 002
umask
( umask 022; exec sg wheel umask)
umask
```

For an alternative solution see my similar post: [How do I set permissions structure for multiple users editing multiple sites in /var/www on Ubuntu 9.10?](https://serverfault.com/questions/127658/how-do-i-set-permissions-structure-for-multiple-users-editing-multiple-sites-in/127686#127686)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script mysg that executes sg arg followed by umask X where X is either 002 or 022 depending on which group was entered. Probably not the most elegant solution...