# Allow Permissions for Multiple FTP Users to Edit Public HTML Folder - Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp

On a dedicated server hosting one website, running Linux with no control panel, I'm trying to grant permission for multiple users to edit the public HTML folder (/var/www/html/).

I want to make sure I do this the best way, I imagine if I set the permissions loosely via CHMOD, it will allow anyone who can reach the folder via FTP to change it. Is the solution to set up a wheel group, add the intended users to the wheel group, and then set the permissions to the wheel group?

Right now, only one user can edit the public HTML.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var/6899#6899

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/127658/how-do-i-set-permissions-structure-for-multiple-users-editing-multiple-sites-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is pretty close to what I'd recommend, but why do you specifically reference the `wheel` group?  On many distributions the group `wheel` has full access to the `sudo` command granting then full root access to the system.

Let's assume you make a new group called `webadmins`:

```
groupadd webadmins
```

Then you want to set the proper permissions to allow your `webadmins` to make changes:

```
chown root:webadmins /var/www/html -R
```

The -R will set the permissions on all existing files.  One issue that's common is if `joe` creates a file in /var/www/html it will, by default, be owned by `joe` and grouped to `joe`'s default group.  We can remedy this by setting the SETGID bit on the parent directory so new files will be grouped to `webadmins` by default:

```
chmod g+s /var/www/html
```

One last issue is that your webserver will need to access these files as well.  I, personally, don't like to leave global read access on /var/www/html because of the likelihood that someone will drop a .php script in there, so I set the directory to 770:

```
chmod 770 /var/www/html
```

And then I add the apache user (`www-data` on RedHat systems, typically) to the `webadmins` group:

```
usermod -aG webadmins www-data
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This isn't ideal because giving Apache write permissions on your website files is a security risk. I wrote a similar answer over here. http://serverfault.com/q/357108/23300

Comment: I like your approach Nic.  You're definitely correct that write permissions from Apache is a security risk.