# Twp different php versions on same machine

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running multiple versions of PHP on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/153391/running-multiple-versions-of-php-on-ubuntu)

I am using ubuntu 12.05 and php 5.3.10
Now i want to use php 5.1.6 also .
So how to run two versions

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered a few times already:

- [How can one run multiple versions of PHP 5.x on a development LAMP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524508/how-can-one-run-multiple-versions-of-php-5-x-on-a-development-lamp-server)
- [Running multiple versions of PHP on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/153391/running-multiple-versions-of-php-on-ubuntu)