# Recommended Setup for Ubuntu Web Server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.10

Sorry if this has been talked about before and please point me to those references. I am now running my own Ubuntu web server however I have been hitting problems with authorities and FTPing up files. Right now I have all of my web stuff under /var/www. But every time I do something there, I then have to do a `chown www-data:www-data` to make sure everything keeps working properly. In reality, I want to be able to FTP into my server upload what I want and just have it work without having to worry about authorities every time.

Should I have put everything under /home/user/public_html/mydomain1.com and home/user/public_html/mydomain2.com? What authorities should that then have? `user:www-data`? `user:user`?

Do I need to make any changes to the Apache config?

Update: How do I setup proFTP to make sure that I can access /var/www if that is the route I continue one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoredache has answered this fairly well already. You should set the UMASK appropriately. His answer is here: [What's the best way of handling permissions for Apache 2's user www-data in /var/www?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var-w)

Comment: What if I moved the sites to /home/users? Just out of curiosity?