# Ubuntu : Add, edit, delete in var/www directory issue

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, fedora

I just installed Ubuntu with LAMP, to use it as development and test server.

Under terminal and using : sudo, I created a php test file and it's working, but I can't copy files using the graphical interface of Ubuntu to the var/www directory.

I can only Create, Copy, Moving files under Terminal using sedo.

How to give the default user permissions to manage the www directory ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider setting up permissions like described in [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var-w/6899#6899).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that but you can set group permissions of /var/www to www-data (rwx) for example (apache's user and group) and you can give the www-data group to your user.

Answer (score 0):

go to shell and write:

```
    chown -R yourusername /var/www/* 
    chmod -R 755 /var/www/*
```

Comment: Giving all files +x is a baaaaaaad idea.