# Setting per-directory umask using ACLs

Tags: linux, permissions, access-control-list, umask, posix

We want to mimic the behavior of a system-wide 002 umask on a certain directory `foo`, in order to ensure the following result:

1. All sub-directories created underneath `foo` will have 775 permissions
2. All files created underneath `foo` and subdirectories will have 664 permissions
3. 1 and 2 will happen for files/dirs created by all users, including root, and all daemons.

Assuming that [ACL is enabled](https://serverfault.com/a/360120/41823) on our partition, this is the command we came up with:

```
setfacl -R -d -m mask:002 foo
```

... but this doesn't work. New files created in the directory end up looking like:

> -rw--w-r--+

When I run `getfacl` on the new file, I get:

> # file: newfile.py
>   # owner: root
>   # group: agroup
>   user::rw-
>   group::rwx        #effective:-w-
>   mask::-w-
>   other::r--

In other words, applying a `mask:200` with ACL is *not* the same as applying `umask 200`.

So *is* there a way to apply a per-directory umask with an ACL?

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical job for ACLs :-)

### Your example

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
```

Set the permissions for the directory itself

```
$ setfacl -m g::rwx -m o::rx  /tmp/foo
```

Set the permissions for the newly created directory and files in that directory.

```
$ setfacl -m default:g::rwx -m o::rx  /tmp/foo
```

Test

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo/bar
$ touch /tmp/foo/bar/baz.py
$ ls -ld /tmp/foo/bar /tmp/foo/bar/baz.py
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 jdoe jdoe 4096 Mar 10 00:06 /tmp/foo/bar
-rw-rw-r--  1 jdoe jdoe    0 Mar 10 00:06 /tmp/foo/bar/baz.py
```

### Explanations

- The concept of mask is very different with ACL and Unix permissions mask. the ACL's mask is an attribute of the file... which restrict the maximum permission granted through ACL (`mask:r-x` + `group:foo:rwx` => effective permissions = `r-x`)
- Warning: modifying the Unix permission of the group, also modifies the ACL's mask (by design!).

### Suggestions

- Use setgid (like `chmod 2755`), so you control which group can write to the file.
- and/or explicitly grant permissions to a group `setfacl -m group:dev_team:rwx`

Comment: @Yarin: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dnotify and script triggered each time a file is created. See: https://serverfault.com/a/127686/30946