# Ubuntu Server Web exposed folder recommended permissions

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way of handling permissions for apache2’s user www-data in /var/www?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var)

I am setting up my first server from scratch and as I am completely novice at this I am not sure if i am doing this right.

I have my web exposed folder at `/var/www` and as I need to it accessible to everyone and writable by group and owner I set its permission to 774.

Is this how things are supposed to be set up or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is to give the least possible permissions/privileges for users. Folders permissions should be generally either `755` (does not provide `w` for group) or `775` (provide `w` for group).

In your case, `774` might not be enough for web server process to access the folder given that it is not the owner and is not a member in its group.