# Setting umask for all users

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, file-permissions, umask

I'm trying to set the default umask to 002 for all users including root on my CentOS box.

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/65416/41823) and other answers, this can be achieved by editing `/etc/profile`. However the comments at the top of that file say:

> It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
>   are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
>   /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
>   will prevent the need for merging in future updates.

So I went ahead and created the following file:
**/etc/profile.d/myapp.sh**
with the single line:

```
umask 002
```

Now, when I create a file logged in as root, the file is born with 664 permissions, the way I had hoped. But files created by my Apache mod_wsgi application, or files created with sudo, still default to 644 permissions...

`$ touch newfile` (as root):
**Result = 664** (Works)

`$ sudo touch newfile`:
**Result = 644** (Doesn't work)

Files created by Apache mod_wsgi app:
**Result = 644** (Doesn't work)

Files created by Python's RotatingFileHandler:
**Result = 644** (Doesn't work)

Why is this happening, and how can I ensure 664 file permissions system wide, no matter what creates the file?

Comment: If by WSGI you mean mod_wsgi, then use mod_wsgi daemon mode and WSGIDaemonProcess has a umask setting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`profile` is a startup file for the shell. Setting `umask 002` in `profile.d` sets it for all users who start their processes from a login shell.

Your two examples are of a different nature. For Apache you might set the umask in the `init.d` script that starts the http server.

For processes started with `sudo` you could use the `umask` option in the sudoers file.

Comment: Dmitri- thanks, this makes sense. How would you deal with files created by a Python process running as root? We're having the same issue with files created by Python's RotatingFileHandler...

Comment: @Yarin I suppose RotatingFileHandler is spawned from root's crontab. You can set umask there.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get the umask thing done is to edit the `/etc/bashrc` file for root and `~/.bashrc` file for other users. Anything you put in `~/.bashrc` for a particular user is gonna override what you put in /etc/profile.

So, find out under which user your apache is running and put umask in the `~./bashrc` file.

This goes for users. It includes interactive user logins and can be get to work by sourcing the files. Doesn't require logging out and in.

But if you are going to set umask for daemons, then you need to get into the init script and put the umask there after it sources the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` file. If you set umask before that, it might not work. But I have seen some daemons which do not work even when you set umask in their init script, a quick example would be cobblerd in RHEL. For that, you need to put umask in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` file itself.

But mostly by putting umask value in `~/.bashrc` file works.

This is how I have got it to work so far, but if other opinions come across, I would be glad to know.

Comment: Thanks @Soham- how do you know the load order of all these scripts?

Comment: @Yarin: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html