# Not everyone can write to new files made in /var/www

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, debian, file-permissions

I followed the most upvoted tips in this thread.

[What's the best way of handling permissions for Apache 2's user www-data in /var/www?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var)

I just made a new file under one user1. However user2 cannot edit it. The files that were all there before I made these permission changes however, both users could edit. I don't want to do the find command every time we make new files. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure user2 has been added to the same group as user1:

grep user2 /etc/group

Should return something like:

> user1:502:user2,user3

Ensure that there are write permissions on the parent directory:

> chmod g+w mydir

Finally add a sticky bit to said directory:

> chmod g+s mydir

If you want further help, you would need to post the output of ls -lhad mydir for the specific parent directory you are having problems modifying files in and the group information for user1 and user2 in /etc/groups (as posted above). You can also check out this [CentOS Guide](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-acls-setting.html), it's written for CentOS 5 but is still applicable for most distros. You can also use the following command to add write permissions for all files and directories within a specific parent directory (so mydir/myfile gets group write access as well):

> chmod -R g+w mydir

Comment: The other answers didn't really do it for me unfortunately. However, my issues were solved with the following Access Control List (ACL) command:

setfacl -Rm d:g:mygroup:rwx /var/www

Which was based off of this answer from  http://serverfault.com/a/7076/252902. I also took advantage of the CentOS link you put up here so thank you for that. Another useful link is http://bencane.com/2012/05/27/acl-using-access-control-lists-on-linux/